# I need to run a python script in crontab for multiple times so i tried like

Tags: linux, cron

[This is my crontab commands my problem is only 1st command is working and others are not what is the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3EE0.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you mean by 'is working and others are not".   What does your test.py script do?  How do you know whether it works or not?  What happens if it works?  What happens if it doesn't work.  One thing to note is that running scripts under cron use a different environment compared to your regular terminal.

Comment: And port text, not images!